# Forwarding response object to same servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, response

```
private void inserTransaction(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) 
{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw =response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<h3>Successfully Transaction has been  Done</h3>");
        pw.close();
        rd.forward(request,response);
}

private void LoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("customerName",v_count);
    session.setAttribute("customerId",V_username);
    session.setAttribute("count",count);
    try{
    if(!v_count.isEmpty())
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/Welcome.jsp");
        try 
        {
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

I want to pass response object from inserTransaction method to LoginSuccess method in same servlet class. Meanwhile LoginSuccess method will redirect to welcome.jsp page where response object from LoginSuccess should include response from both methods.

Comment: Don't know what you are expecting. In `inserTransaction` you send the HTTP Header and a `<H3>` Tag. After this you want append the whole `jsp/Welcome.jsp` - maybe with HTML Header etc?

Comment: I want to display servlet level developed html i.e"<h3>Successfully Transaction has been Done</h3>" in welcome.jsp. where Welcome.jsp already been used to display some other content.So I want welcome.jsp include response from above mentioned both methods.

Comment: This is not possible. You need to use a template system like facelets (XHTML). Or you only add an attribute `request.setAttribute("message","Successfully Transaction has been  Done")` in `insertTransaction` and then call `LoginSuccess` and on your `welcome.jsp` you can insert `<% if (request.getAttribute("message") != null){  %><h3><%= request.getAttribute("message") %></h3><% } %>` where you want to show the message.

Comment: Although you can pass the response object to another method, only ONE of the methods can do anything with it. This is how the Servlet API itself routes GET requests to doGet and POST to doPost, from the Service method.